# How to get last object from a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, loops

I have a `listView` and I am showing `students attendance` for each subject, I am parsing `JSON` till `secondlast` place for that. For that, in get count I did return `attendanceBeanList.size()-1`. See below code.
I have done this:

```
 private List<TotalAttendance_Bean> attendanceBeanList;
 public TotalAttendanceAdapter(Activity activity, List<TotalAttendance_Bean> attendanceBeanList)
{
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.attendanceBeanList = attendanceBeanList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return attendanceBeanList.size()-1;
}
```

Now when I am going to get last object I am stuck. I have to get Total attendance for every student. For that I have to get Last Object from below `JSONArray`.

This is my JSON:

```
[
  {
    "subject_name": "English-I",
    "total_classes": "2",
    "total_attended": "2",
    "percentage": "100"
  },
  {
    "subject_name": "English-I",
    "total_classes": "2",
    "total_attended": "2",
    "percentage": "100"
  },
  {
      "subject_name": "English-I",
      "total_classes": "2",
      "total_attended": "2",
      "percentage": "100"
  },
  {
     "subject_name": "English-I",
     "total_classes": "2",
     "total_attended": "2",
     "percentage": "100"
 },
  {
      "total_attendance": 90%
  }
]
```

This is my XML.
In this layout I am showing Every Subject Attendance in List View, and I have to show Total percentage in TextView in Blue Colour.
[image: layout]

Comment: The Json you've posted is not valid, check with a validator and correct the code

Comment: Sir I have checked that also, it is showing  "Valid JSON". Can't we do in this JSON

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fetch your `total_attendance` after parsing all `students` records

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(yourStringResponse);

// get the last object
JSONObject tot_obj = obj.getJSONObject(obj.length()-1);

// get String from last object
String tot_str = tot_obj.optString("total_attendance");
```

Note : `optString` will convert your data to `String` otherwise it will give an empty `string` like `""`.

Now you can display the data in your `Activity`'s `TextView` like

```
yourTextView.setText(tot_str);
```

you can pass your `tot_str` to `Adapter` if you need

```
public TotalAttendanceAdapter(Activity activity
                        , List<TotalAttendance_Bean> attendanceBeanList
                        , String tot)
{
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.attendanceBeanList = attendanceBeanList;
    this.tot = tot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get the last object from a JSONArray in android kotlin**

> First method

```
val bookings = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result")
val lastObj: JSONObject = bookings.getJSONObject((bookings.length() - 1))
hAddress.text = lastObj.optString("service_location")
hDate.text = lastObj.optString("visit_date")
hTime.text = lastObj.optString("visit_time")
```

> Second method

```
val bookings = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result")
for (i1 in 0 until bookings.length()) {
    val c1: JSONObject = bookings.getJSONObject(i1)
    hAddress.text = c1.optString("service_location")
    hDate.text = c1.optString("visit_date")
    hTime.text = c1.optString("visit_time")
}
```